# C# Change generic object after it is instantiated?

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to change TEntity to NewEntity after SomeClass has been instantiated?

For example, take this class definition:

```
public class SomeClass<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
   public void ChangeSet<NewEntity>()
    {
        TEntity = NewEntity;//not valid
    }
 }
```

Instantiated for example like this:

```
var sc = new SomeClass<SomeEntity>();
```

How can I accomplish this?

```
sc.ChangeSet<NewEntity>();
```

Comment: No; that's totally impossible.  You cannot change an object's type at runtime.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Slaks - I have a generic repository and I am trying to allow it to change type during runtime without having to re-instantiate it.

Comment: does NewEntity and Tentity has  a relationship between them ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Nope, they are different classes with no relation.

Comment: does NewEntity and Tentity inherit from the same class ?

Comment: @TravisJ: That doesn't make any sense.  Any typed variable holding the repository would become invalid.  If you try to formulate a complete code sample that uses this mythical feature, you should see why it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Slaks - You are right. I have complete code but was trying to give a localized example. The error produced read `Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<NewEntity>' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TEntity>'`. Perhaps I will just try to wrap the repository in a unit of work pattern so I can use the new keyword to instantiate with different types but still keep some state variables.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a set of `TEntity` objects into a set of `NewEntity` objects?  If so, that's possible, but you haven't hit on the correct syntax for doing it.

Comment: @phoog - That was most of what I was after, yes. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I have added an answer with some elaboration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to change TEntity to NewEntity after SomeClass has been instantiated?

**No**, this is not possible. How would the CLR know how to map the values from `TEntity` to `SomeEntity`? They are different types. It would be like asking your grocer to turn an apple into an orange.

The code below **is not recommended**. There are so many problems you would have to worry about, and it would be prone to bugs. I am providing it as an example of what you are asking the CLR to do.

```
SomeClass<Foo> fooClass = new SomeClass<Foo>():
//do stuff to fooClass
SomeClass<Baz> = fooClass.ChangeSet<Baz>();

public class SomeClass<T> where T : class
{
    public SomeClass<K> ChangeSet<K>() where K:class
    {
       var changed = new SomeClass<K>();
       //manually map the properties over
       //but how do you know that Foo.PropertyA fits into Baz.PropetyZed?
       //what happens if Foo.A has a string length of 100, but Baz.A has a max length of 50? What do you do?
       //What id Foo.ID is an INT and Baz.ID is a GUID?
       return changed;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure you got the point of the code, so your code really isn't a solution. Everything above "the code below" is good and constitutes a solid answer.

Comment: The snippet isnt supposed to show you how to do it. I put it together so you could visualize what you were asking. The clr to do

Answer (score 2):

Generics are used to enforce type safety at compile time.  It is better to look at the `new SomeClass<SomeEntity>()` as an actual class itself.  In fact, it IS compiled as a class.  Which you can see based on the following example of a static field in a generic class:

```
public class GenericTest<T> where T : class   
{
    public static int StaticIntField { get; set; }

    public GenericTest(int setGenericIntField)
    {
        StaticIntField = setGenericIntField;
    }
}
```

Test it with this:

```
var stringTest =new  GenericTest<string>(1);
var objectTest = new GenericTest<object>(2);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(GenericTest<string>.StaticIntField.ToString()); //<-- prints 1
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(GenericTest<object>.StaticIntField.ToString()); //<-- prints 2
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(GenericTest<Control>.StaticIntField.ToString()); //<-- prints 0 because we haven't created an instance of this type yet
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to convert a set of TEntity objects into a set of NewEntity objects? If so, that's possible, but you haven't hit on the correct syntax for doing it.

> That was most of what I was after, yes. Can you elaborate a little?

Suppose you have a generic class `C<T>`, that represents a set of `T` instances, and you'd like to convert that into an instance of the generic class `C<U>`; a set of `U` instances.  You can't change the type of the `C<T>` instance, but you *can* create a new object whose type is `C<U>`.  The signature would be:

```
public class C<T>
{
    public C<U> Convert<U>()
    {
        C<U> result = new C<U>();
        // populate the result somehow
        return result;
    }
}
```

For the sake of providing an implementation, further suppose that the mechanism for converting a set of `T` instances into a set of `U` instances is to convert each `T` into a `U`.  You can provide a `Func<T, U>` to effect the conversion.  We'll also provide a constructor for `C<T>` that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` to populate the set:

```
public class C<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> _items;
    public C(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        _items = items;
    }
    public C<U> Convert<U>(Func<T, U> convertElement)
    {
        return new C<U>(_items.Select(convertElement));
    }
}
```

We could use this as is, though at this point all we've done is put a clumsy wrapper around linq to objects:

```
void DoSomething()
{
    var integersOneToTen = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
    var myClassOfIntegers = new C<int>(integersOneToTen);

    Func<int, string> converter = i => i.ToString();

    var myClassOfStrings = myClassOfIntegers.Convert<string>(converter); // the compiler can infer the type argument, but I've included it to reduce ambiguity.
}
```

Some of this may be incompatible with your needs; if that's so, post a comment, and I'll try to adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great example of converting using generics. +1

Answer (score 1):

The generic parameter is a compile time template for the class.  So, when you have `SomeClass<TEntity>` instantiated as `SomeClass<int>`, you're more or less telling the compiler that you have a type that is "Some Class as applied to int".

Now, at run time you want to be able to redefine "SomeClass as applied to int" as "SomeClass as applied to {whatever}".  But, the "as applied to part" needs to be specified at compiled time, so you can't do this.

Another way to think of it is imagine if this were implemented in general.  For example, imagine a `ChangeSet<T>` method on int where someone could suddenly turn your ints into strings or objects or Foos.  Not cast them, mind you, but change the class definition of int at runtime.  Yikes!